# Set environment variables to Allure report from pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, allure, autotest

I'm running Jenkins parameterized jobs with the following pipeline configuration of `allure` step:

```
stage('Generate reports') {
    allure([
        includeProperties: false,
        jdk              : '',
        properties       : [],
        reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS'
        results          : [[path: webdriverTestResultsPath], [path: unitTestResultsPath]]])
}
```

Build's parameters, which are set before starting the job, become available within `getEnv()` in my tests. I'd like to show some of them in the `Environment` section of Allure report's dashboard. For instance, there is a HOST build parameter which specifies the base application url.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclosure: I've created Java library which deals with this issue: https://github.com/AutomatedOwl/allure-environment-writer

It uses TransformerFactory to write the environment.xml to the allure-results path in any stage of the test. It also checks for the directory existence in case running from cleaned build.

Usage example:

```
import static com.github.automatedowl.tools.AllureEnvironmentWriter.allureEnvironmentWriter;

public class SomeTests {

    @BeforeSuite
    void setAllureEnvironment() {
        allureEnvironmentWriter(
                ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder()
                        .put("Browser", "Chrome")
                        .put("Browser.Version", "70.0.3538.77")
                        .put("URL", "http://testjs.site88.net")
                        .build(), System.getProperty("user.dir")
                        + "/allure-results/");
    }

    @Test
    void someTest() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also utilize *environment.properties* file, the format of the file:

```
Browser=Chrome
Browser.Version=63.0
Stand=Production
```

**source**: https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_environment

File location: allure-results directory (eg. target/allure-results)

You can generate the file in your pipeline before the allure report is generated.

**Gitlab pipeline example:**

```
publish-reports:
  extends:
    - .runner
  stage: report-results
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - allure-results
    expire_in: 14 days
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p target/allure-results || true  
  script:
    - echo "============== PREPARE ALLURE ENV VARIABLES FILE =========================="
    - echo "Browser=${VAR_BROWSER}" > target/allure-results/environment.properties
    - echo "BrowserVersion=${VAR_BROWSER_VERSION}" >> target/allure-results/environment.properties
    - echo "Stand=${VAR_STAND}" >> target/allure-results/environment.properties

    - echo "============== GENERATING ALLURE REPORTS STATIC WEB PAGE ================="
    - cp -rp allure-results target/allure-results/
    - mvn --settings ${M2SETTINGS} allure:report
```